# What is the importance of CoreCLR, PCL and WinRT in Azure-Storage-Net change log

Tags: azure, windows-runtime, azure-storage, coreclr

I was inspecting the change log of Windows Azure Storage nuget from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/changelog.txt). I do not get the usage of `CoreCLR`, `PCL` and `WinRT`.

For instance

> Changes in 7.2.0 :
>
> - All (CoreCLR): NetStandard target framework changed to netstandard1.3
> - All (PCL): Removed support for PCL in favor of NetStandard GA release
> - ...
>
> Changes in 7.1.2 :
>
> - ...
> - All (WinRT): Fixed a bug where HttpClient default timeout caused unhandled TaskCancellation exceptions.
> - ...

A simple search on google tells that `CoreCLR` is a *.NET execution engine* and `WinRT` stands for *Windows Runtime*. I do not know what `PCL` is.

So what is the importance of these in change log in simple terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those represent versions of the package capable of running on different versions of .Net:

- WinRT is used in Windows Store apps, it uses a trimmed version of .Net
- PCL is short for Portable Class Library, the old approach of targeting multiple versions of .Net from a single library
- [NetStandard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) is a new approach of targeting multiple versions of .Net, that came along with .Net Core, the new modular cross-platform version of .Net
- CoreCLR is the runtime used by .Net Core, though marking changes to NetStandard version of the library as "CoreCLR" is confusing